# How to change email address via gitlab-rails (avoid email reconfirmation)

Tags: gitlab

While I am waiting for a merge request to be introduced to Gitlab to avoid this problem I need a workaround to edit an user's email address via the gitlab-rails console.

Using this:

```
user = User.find_by(name: 'test')
user.email = 'test@example.com'
user.save
```

allows to edit the user but I am asked to confirm the new email before it is applied. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it afterwards, so in case someone has the same problem:

```
gitlab-rails runner '
                      user = User.find_by(name: 'test')
                      user.email = 'test@test.com'
                      user.skip_reconfirmation!
                      user.save
                    '
```

EDIT: This used to work in old version, but is no longer required as I contributed to add a skip confirmation when using the Users API: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#add-email-for-user

Comment: in case someone needs it: you can also query by other attributes i.e. `username` would be -> `User.find_by(username: 'root')`

Comment: I myself added the possibility of skipping email reconfirmation through the API and is now upstream: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#user-modification

Comment: @djuarez thanks for contributing, but it doesn't seem to work for me. When I use `user.save` I get back `false` and when I use `user.save!` I get `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Notification email can't be blank, Notification email is invalid)`

Comment: @0xC0000022L I am no longer investing time in the latest GitLab versions but I contributed so it can be done through the API, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might have another option with [GitLab 15.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/10/22/gitlab-15-5-released/#modify-users-commit-email-through-the-users-api) (October 2022)

> ### Modify user’s commit email through the Users API
>
> Previously, a user’s commit email could be modified only in the UI.
>
> Now, administrators can use the Users API to modify the commit email and perform this as a bulk action.
>
> Thank you [Neil Drumm](https://gitlab.com/drumm) for your contribution!
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#user-modification) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/375148).

Context:

> In the Drupal community we provision contributor user accounts in our GitLab instance (`git.drupalcode.org`) automatically from their `Drupal.org` user accounts.
>
> In the past, we used `Drupal.org` to manage multiple email accounts per user, and to provide a no-reply '`private`' commit email.
>
> We would like to migrate multiple email account handling to GitLab, but at the same time we want to be able to bulk set the public `commit_email` of users to the GitLab provided `no-reply` address to preserve privacy.