# Сhanging users ' email addresses with GitLab API

Tags: gitlab-api

I need to write a python script for GitLab that allows me to change the email addresses of users

The problem is that I manage to change various user attributes, such as "bio" and etc
But I can't change the "email".
The script reports a successful change of these attributes, but in fact they do not change.

I am working as the root user, using his token

To change the user attributes, I use this construction

```
gl = gitlab.Gitlab(arg.url, private_token=arg.token)
user = gl.users.list(username = 'name')[0]
user.bio = f"{user.username}@EXAMPLE.COM"
user.save()
```

I also tried working with classic requests, instead of the gitlab library, but the result was the same

Comment: I believe that this may solve your problem [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134290/how-to-change-email-address-via-gitlab-rails-avoid-email-reconfirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134290/how-to-change-email-address-via-gitlab-rails-avoid-email-reconfirmation)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the problem lies in [this error](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/25077) of gitlab itself. This error persists up to version 14.0.10. Perhaps it was fixed in subsequent updates, I did not check.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).